# Download Google Storage file using acl and redirect

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, google-cloud-storage, acl, restful-architecture

Users can download csv-files från my Google App Enigne-application.
Larger files hit the 1min timeout-window and I have re-imagened my solution giving users read-access in Storage-ACL and redirecting to a downloadlink.

This is a working example for giving the user access and redirects to "https://storage.cloud.google.com/[bucket]/[object]" (1)

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())
acl = bucket.acl
acl.user(ndb_user.primaryEmail).grant_read()
acl.save()

self.redirect("https://storage.cloud.google.com" + filename)
```

It seems my solution don't work programatically nor in-browser.
Any ideas why or suggestions on alternatives ways to actually do this?

1: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-uris

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because you are only granting READ access on the bucket via the the ACL api.  This maps to the IAM Role `roles/storage.legacyBucketReader`, which does not grant `storage.objects.get` permission (it only `grants storage.buckets.get` and `storage.objects.list`).  If you switch to the [new IAM api](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/setIamPolicy), and instead grant `roles/storage.objectViewer` this should work.

That being said, I strongly recommend looking at [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) instead.  Signed URLs will grant temporary access via delegation rather than permanently granting the user access via ACLs and is made for precisely this use case.  Google's google-cloud library has a "generate_signed_url" function you can use to generate them instead of rolling your own.  Here is the [documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage-blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.generate_signed_url).